# Loading typescript external module without importing?

Tags: node.js, express, typescript

I am having a headache at the moment because I am writing a nodejs typescript app which is basically one big internal module (spread over lots of files and outputted as one).

Now the problem I have is that `express.d.ts` (found on definitely typed) is written so it can only be loaded as an external module: `import express = require("express");` however then that means that I have to compile my application as a single file as the moment you put the `import` keyword in it treats it like your module is now external, which I do not want.

So is there any way for me to change this code:

```
/// <reference path="../../../typescript-descriptors/express/express.d.ts" />
import express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', (req: express.Request, res: express.Response) => {
    res.render('index');
});
```

so it does not require the import and I can just do `var express = require("express");` and still get the type safety?

As I NEED to be able to split my TS logic over multiple files and using the import method does not allow this.

Comment: A couple of comments:
1. [TSD is now depricated](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/tsd/issues/269). You should migrate to [Typings](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typings).
2. I suggest using the `from` keyword when importing:
`import * as express from "express";`
You can then use `req: express.Request` in your callback

Answer (score 0):

Updated based on the comment...

Express itself is what TypeScript calls an external module. It is not possible to import an external module into an internal module - so you can't actually achieve what you want directly here.

However, if the real underlying problem is...

> As I NEED to be able to split my TS logic over multiple files and using the import method does not allow this

What is stopping you from simply switching to external modules, which allows you to split your logic into many files and import them as needed? Rather than trying to combine the output into a single file - lean on the simple module loading that Node gives you for free and you're back in the game!

Comment: The require does not seem to be an issue as the node.d.ts reference seems to include that (not included here). The problem I have doing this (which I should have made clearer) is that where I have `req: express.Request` it tells me it cannot find the type. I have tried `req: Express.Request` that tells me that Request is missing the method <some method name>.

Comment: as its all done via a build script it would mean every individual file would need compiling via TSC and then packaging in a certain place and would become a nightmare to maintain. Also there should be no need for me to change my entire architecture just to get type safety from a *.d.ts file, they are there to provide type descriptions not enforce a pattern or practice hence why I want to just use the type descriptions within there but not its module loading paradigm, I have more pros for using internal modules than external modules currently.

Comment: It isn't really the type definition that is stopping you to be fair - the type definition is just describing the reality of Node and Express. I understand your frustration though.

Comment: Currently I am unable to use the type definition unless I load the typescript module as an external module. The moment I do that it requires my typescript file to be compiled as an external module. So it seems like it is the type definition that is stopping me, as to me there should be no reason why TS needs to know anything more than  there is a reference that describes Express types, which is all I want it to do, much like how I use any other d.ts file, however I cannot use the types within this d.ts file without importing the module via TS (not JS).

Comment: Why not write a type definition that does what you want instead?

Comment: That is what I am currently doing, its just not very future-proof, although saying that express.d.ts is still on version 3.1 not 4.x so I guess its a moot point.